# Please help me solve this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics, approximate-integration

Please help me solve this integral
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\varepsilon_r-\sin^2\varphi}\cos^2\varphi\ d\varphi.
\end{align}
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is $\varepsilon_r\ge1$?

Comment: You should show your own working out so far as part of your question.

Comment: Use substitution $t=\sin{\varphi}$. Then you simply calculate the primitive of $(\epsilon_r-t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}t$. Mind the new limits of integration.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yes $\varepsilon_r>1$

Comment: @Medo I have tried this but it looks like $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\varepsilon_r-\sin^2\varphi}\cos\varphi\ d\sin\varphi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint:

In [Elliptic Inegrals of Hancock](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00085HTBU), your integral appears. It shows that it can be evaluated with elliptic integrals:

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\varepsilon_r-\sin^2\varphi}\cos^2\varphi\ d\varphi. = 2\sqrt{\varepsilon_{r}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}}\sin^2\varphi}\cos^2\varphi\ d\varphi.$$

Using the notation of elliptic integrals:

$$\int_{0}^{\theta}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\varphi}\cos^2\varphi\ d\varphi = \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}\sin\theta\cos\theta + \frac{1+k^2}{3k^2}E(k,\theta) - \frac{k'^2}{3k^2}F(k,\theta)$$

where $k$ is the modulus and $k'$ is the complementary modulus and

$k'= \sqrt{1-k}$

and

$$ F(k,\theta) = \int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}$$

$$ E(k,\theta) = \int_{0}^{\theta} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi} d\phi$$

are the incomplete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, respectively.

If you put $\displaystyle k^2 = \frac{1}{\varepsilon_{r}}$ and $\displaystyle \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we have your integral.

Comment: The author died in 1944. It [seems ok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_term) to give a link to his works online: https://archive.org/details/ellipticintegral00hancuoft